# How to implement sineWaveTo squareWaveTo and sawWaveTo lines in html5 canvas 2d context?

Tags: html, canvas, drawing, trigonometry, waveform

I would like to try an implement these so that they can be used in a manner similar to lineTo(). Starting from the current point, given the ending coordinates the functions would draw either a square, saw, or sine line all the way to the the ending coordinates.

<strike>I dont know if we can factor in both Amplitude AND Frequency because I guess it would cause problems with the line actually finishing on the ending point but calculating frequency from distance and amplitude should.</strike>

Amplitude and Frequency as parameters *should* be possible, assuming we adjust the frequency proportional to the distance.

So far, all i've found is examples in ActionScript and I cant seem to purpose-fit them to a non-animated line drawing function like I want to.

Any help is greatly appreciated, so far I've come up with whole sorts of funky spirals but nothing close to the goal. I'm not much of a math buff so pseudo code welcome ;)

Hahahah, "tumbleweed badge"... methinks overflowed the mental stacks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for good measure. Does only sin(), but, I'm sure you'll be able to figure out the rest.  (Tested only in Firefox, BTW.)

```
<html>

<head>
<title>sin()</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/resources/dojo.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
#id_canvas { border:5px solid gray }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

dojo.require( "dijit.form.VerticalSlider" );
dojo.require( "dijit.form.HorizontalSlider" );
dojo.require( "dijit.form.HorizontalRule" );
dojo.require( "dijit.form.VerticalRule" );
dojo.require( "dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels" );
dojo.require( "dijit.form.VerticalRuleLabels" );
dojo.require( "dojo.parser" );

function myHandler() {

    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, 640, 480 );

    var amp = dijit.byId('slider2').attr("value");
    var period = 1/dijit.byId('slider1').attr("value");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 240);
    for( i = 0; i <= 640; i++ ) {
        ctx.lineTo(i, 240 - Math.sin( (i / 640) / period ) * amp);
    }

    ctx.stroke();

}

var canvas = null;
var ctx = null;

dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('id_canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    myHandler();
});

</script>

<body class="claro">

<table class="bla">
<tr>
    <td><canvas id="id_canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <div dojoType="dijit.form.VerticalSlider" name="horizontal1"
            noValueIndicator="<span style='color:silver'>Click to edit</span>"
            onChange="myHandler()"
            value="100"
            minimum="-240"
            maximum="240"
            pageIncrement="100"
            showButtons="false"
            intermediateChanges="true"
            slideDuration="1"
            style="margin-left:40px; width:30px; height: 480px;"
            id="slider2"
        ></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <br/>
    <br/>
        <div dojoType="dijit.form.HorizontalSlider" name="horizontal1"
            noValueIndicator="<span style='color:silver'>Click to edit</span>"
            onChange="myHandler()"
            value="6.28291"
            maximum="12.5663706"
            minimum="0"
            pageIncrement="100"
            showButtons="false"
            intermediateChanges="true"
            slideDuration="1"
            style="margin-left:40px; width:600px; height: 30px;"
            id="slider1"
        >
            <div dojoType="dijit.form.HorizontalRule" container="bottomDecoration" count=11 style="height:5px;"></div>
            <ol dojoType="dijit.form.HorizontalRuleLabels" container="bottomDecoration" style="height:1em;font-size:12px;">
                <li>0</li>
                <li>PI</li>
                <li>2PI</li>
                <li>3PI</li>
                <li>4PI</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Looks like: [image]

Comment: You answer is a good answer but I dont feel it answers my question because I have been down that path.

Comment: Yet, I blame only the formulation of my question for which I have to rework. But yes, that is the general formula for a sine wave, then I realized that in order to achieve a multi-form function to accomplish this, the final implementation would be more to the level of what bevierCurveTo does ie: calculating cartesian points and deriving calculations from that. I would'nt say that's exactly what it does internally but I do know that that is what I have to do... my ideal waveform function would accept from Ax,Ay to Bx,By amp, freq, shape and if it must: draw an angled wave from A to B of "shape"

Comment: Then again, maybe I'm totally off on this, maybe i need to think about using ctx.rotate,translate to A and just incrementally draw wave cycles until B and rotate,translate back?